Mic and Audio not working in some weird scenarios
Sorry for the spaghetti english.
I have ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer Swift 3 SF314-41.
The first issue is with my earphones, if i leave them plug in when i start my notebook the audio and the mic are not working, but if i re-plug the earphones they works good.
The second issue is more rare but sometimes my mic not work and start to switch without stop between ext and int, whatever there is sound play on notebook, in this case i need to restart the notebook to make it work again.
The gif of the switching problem to be more clear
